# Flutter Build APK: Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, apk

I have been facing this problem only in **Release Mode** in Debug mode its working fine.

**I'm using `firebase_core` and `firebase_storage` plugins only**

#### ⚠ Exception

[image]

#### Flutter Doctor

[image]

Followed all the steps of integrating Firebase in Flutter:

#### Step 1:

Added in `main.dart` before `runApp()`

- `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`
- `await Firebase.initializeApp();`

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

#### Step 2:

Added in `build.gradle` root folder

- `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' <-- // here it is
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

#### Step 3:

Added in `build.gradle` app level

- `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' <--- // here it is
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

#### Step 4:

- Updated the `firebase_core`
- Updated the `firebase_storage`

#### Step 5:

Added the `google-service.json` to app level

[image]

I have already gone through the solutions available on Stack Overflow. Hence, whatever link you are going to shared, I might have gone through it already.

**Please let me know if you need anything else :)**

Comment: I'm assuming you have added the google-services.json file within your app level folder of android? (`android/app/google-services.json`)

Comment: Yes, already done that too. Let me update the question for this step as well

Comment: Have you added `google-services.json`? This can be obtained from firebase console. This config is required for firebase libraries to work. reference - https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file. * Ignore my comment. Just saw yours*

Comment: Yes already did that, its update in question now :)

Comment: Have you tested to see if adding the multidex module works?

Comment: Yes, multidex is already there

Comment: Might be related to *applicationIdentifier*. Is your release version of Application identifier e.g. `com.myapp` is registered in firebase console?

Comment: Yup, the app was working fine 2-3 days back I have build like 7 to 8 APKs for testing. But failed just now

Comment: Sometimes the kotlin version mentioned in the gradle file conflicts with the classpath version. I just faced this issue a couple of days back and I had to use the right combination of those. Try that maybe